# Orthogonality of sum of sine

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonality

Define $$v_{lk}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{m+1}}\sin\left(\frac{kl\pi}{m+1}\right)$$
where $k,l=1,\ldots,m$.

My textbook claims the following statements, but I don't see how either follow.

1. $$\sum_{l=1}^m\sin^2\left(\frac{k l \pi}{m+1}\right)=\frac{m+1}{2}$$
2. $$\sum_{l=1}^m v_{lk}v_{lj}=\delta_{kj}$$

Assuming the first claim, it's easy to see that if $k=j$, then $\sum_{l=1}^m v_{lk}v_{lj}=1.$
However, after trying several trig identities, namely the product of sines, I haven't been able to work out how the sum is zero.

How exactly can I see that these two claims hold?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Put $$\theta=\frac {2k\pi}{m+1} $$

use
$$\sin^2 (\theta/2)=\frac {1-\cos (\theta)}{2} $$

and
$$\sum_{l=1}^m \cos (l \theta)=Re (\sum_{l=1}^m (e^{i\theta})^l )$$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to use the last line. I see that from $\theta=\frac{2\pi k}{m+1}$, if $\frac{kl}{m+1}\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\Re\left( \exp(i\theta l)\right)=1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Moreover, how does this hint help with the second bulleted item?